# How do I send a character to a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need to emulate user input of a character into a textarea, e.g. ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neBqw/4/))

```
<textarea rows=3 cols='30' id='txt'></textarea>

<script>

var $txt = jQuery('#txt')    
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 49;    
$txt.focus().trigger(e)

</script>
```

It correctly sets focus on the textarea but character '1' (ASCII code 49) doesn't appear in the text box. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Based on the answers, I see that I didn't supply enough information, so here it goes: The point is not to just change the value of the text area, but to actually emulate a user enter that value using keyboard. I am trying to hook into some SharePoint control, and it does funky stuff when user presses a certain key in a certain textarea. Just adding some value via val() won't do me any good as all the correct key events need to be triggered.

So, the question is still there - how do I emulate user input based on what I tried in the example above?

Comment: why not manipulate the textarea value directly? $txt.val($txt.val() + "X");

Comment: Why not...append the character instead of "simulating" a keyboard press?

Comment: I think you should update the title of the question - you want to "emulate a user key press", not "send a character to a text area".

Answer (score 2):

Use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead:

```
var $txt = jQuery('#txt');
$txt.focus().val('1');
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/neBqw/6/).

And really, you don't even need the `focus()` method to do this, unless it's serving a different purpose. Using `val()` alone will work.

You can also do this with pure JavaScript:

```
var txt = document.getElementById("txt");
txt.value = "1";
```

Comment: The point is not to just change the value of the text area, but to actually emulate a user enter that value using keyboard. I am trying to hook into some SharePoint control, and it does funky stuff when user presses a certain key in a certain textarea.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest a combination of `val()` and `trigger()`. Something like this: `$txt.val('1').trigger('change')`

Comment: it's not the same as what happens when a user actually presses that key on the keyboard. I need full emulation of a user pressing a key in the textarea

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simulate keyboard for testing, try...

```
var $txt = jQuery('#txt');
$txt.val('1');
$txt.trigger('change'); // keypress, whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the end of your script to append the character to your text area.

```
jQuery('#txt').append(String.fromCharCode(49));
```